# Do different Akan varities (Asante, Bono, Fante) in Ghana still have separate written standards in use in the current education system and media?

Tags: sociolinguistics, african-languages

There are four varieties of Akan that have at some point been developed as distinct written standards: Asante, Akuapem, Bono and Fante. However schools today in all the Akan-speaking regions seem to use a "standard Akan" which corresponds to Akuapem. Are written Asante, Bono and Fante still in use in the education system, perhaps as language subjects rather than the medium of instruction? The medium of instruction in Akan-speaking areas seems to always be either English or the standard Akan Orthography Committee register of Akan based on Akuapem. The general public understanding is that Akan is a single language while Asante, Akuapem, Bono, Fante and other varieties are dialects of Akan. Therefore the written Akan in the Ashanti region mostly seems to be the standard AOC Akan (based on Akuapem) rather than Asante written as it is spoken.